# Is "to wear" also used as a "dynamic verb" meaning "to don", "to put on"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

My intuition was that the verb [*to **wear***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear#Etymology_2) could be used in two ways (besides all its other senses that is.)

1. A ["stative"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb) sense related to the state of having clothes (etc) on.
2. A ["dynamic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_verb) sense related to the action of ***[putting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_on)*** clothes ***[on](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_on)***, ***[donning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don#Etymology_2)*** clothes.

I was surprised to find that all the dictionaries I've checked online support only the first, stative sense, and none supported the second, dynamic sense.

Is my intuition at fault? Are the dictionaries just being a tad prescriptive with this? What do other sources such as grammar and other fields of linguistics have to say about this, if anything?

---

I've found some supporting evidence for my intuition in [the Wikipedia article for *stative verbs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb#Dowty.27s_analysis):

`3.` They do not occur as imperatives, except when used in an inchoative manner.

- Run!
- *Know the answer!
- Know thyself! (inchoative, not stative; archaic)

Examples of dynamic *wear* I can think up are mostly imperatives:

- **Wear** a coat if you're going outside!

(But I've never had a good grasp of the *inchoative*, so maybe there's a gap, or maybe it depends on who is analysing?

Comment: The only relevant field is lexicology. Sometimes, I've queried omissions in dictionaries myself: they're not perfect. But then neither am I. Dictionaries include or omit words and senses for words after analysing substantial corpora, so they're almost always more authoritative than any individual's perceptions. However, as OED contains more words and senses than other English dictionaries, it's often seen as the final arbiter. Perhaps the sense 'don' is given there. The fact that neither of us can find it elsewhere persuades me I'm wise not to use it.

Comment: Well most dictionaries don't get further into verb typology than transitive vs intransitive, though they may distinguish other types via the wording of the senses. Then again I don't have access to the biggest online dictionaries like the full OED (though I do have one in storage).

Comment: This thread on our linguistics sister site may be of some interest regarding English verbs beyond lexicography: [English verbs - how many types/classifications?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8698)

Comment: I don't think so; you have to *put on* a coat in order to *wear* it, but that doesn't mean that they mean the same thing. You could say *"put on your coat before you go outside"*, but you wouldn't say *"wear your coat before you go outside"*.

Comment: @PeterShor: I did struggle to think up an example. But here's the kind of thing I can find on [Google Books](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=kwQGDvO1lykC&pg=PA200&dq=%22wear+a+OR+your%22+-%22to+wear%22+-%22you+wear%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0TwDVKeNA4_f8AXJwIL4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22wear%20a%20OR%20your%22%20-%22to%20wear%22%20-%22you%20wear%22&f=false): **Wear** your seat belt, **wear** a helmet, and **wear** knee and elbow pads. **Wear** a life jacket, **wear** sunscreen, and protect your eyes by **wearing** sunglasses. **Wear** a jacket, a scarf, hat, gloves, or mittens when it's cold.

Comment: The technical terms are _active_ and _stative_; "dynamic" and "static" are not definitions but impressions. And they're not at issue here -- _wear_ is active and can be used in the imperative and progressive. _Get_ or _become_ or _come_ or _go_ are frequent English auxiliaries in inchoative constructions (and there are a number of them, and they swing both ways with causatives, of which there are also lots). In other words, inchoation/causation and active/stative are independent dimensions, producing a 4-way paradigm (not that paradigms are much use in syntax).

Comment: I haven't used the term "static" anywhere. I originally used the term "active verb" but found that on both Wikipedia and linguistics.stackexchange the term "dynamic verb" seemed to be preferred so I went back and edited the wording of my question here.

Comment: Perhaps the best comparison I can come up with is 'Carry a can of mace if you live in that sort of area'. There is an implication of continuous (recommended) compliance, but no direct inchoative aspect ('Start carrying a can of mace'). Leaving terminology aside, does OED give the sense 'don / put on' for 'wear'?

Comment: You have to put something on in order to wear it, but that doesn't mean that the words are synonymous. It's just a logical relationship. You wouldn't say that _drive_ means _get into_ when referring to a car, would you?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker. I understand the logic but I'm asking about the senses. In fact your example is flawed because both *drive* and *get into* are dynamic/active verbs. Whether a verb/sense is dynamic or stative is independent of its semantic and logic. But I accept that most people are probably unaware of concepts like active/dynamic/stative verbs. Perhaps this question is better suited to linguistics.SE.

Comment: I'd love to go out, but I haven't got a thing to wear. Perhaps I'm also feeling a bit *worn* down.

Comment: A common mistranslation often made by Chinese people is to tell you, if it’s cold and they think you're not wearing enough, to “You should wear more clothes!” (from “你多穿点衣服吧”). What they actually mean is “You should put on some more clothes”, but Chinese uses 穿 for both the active/inchoative verb and the stative/progressive aspects of the action.

Comment: “You should wear more clothes!” is completely unexceptional English by my idiolect. (Middle aged Australian from Melbourne.)

Answer (score 4):

"I'm wearing the coat" means that I already have a coat on, not that I'm putting on a coat.

When *wear* is used in the imperative sense, typically what is meant that the person should arrive somewhere later with the clothing on already, or include the clothing as part of getting dressed fully, not immediately put on the clothing at that moment.

If for some reason someone wanted to tell someone to put something on using the word *wear* it would generally need a *now* with it - i.e. "Wear these gloves now."

Comment: Well, the imperative *wear* could need some time-frame stated; it doesn't need to be *now* though. "Wear gloves when you take dinner out of the oven."

Answer (score -2):

He will don his coat 
He will wear his coat 
She will don a coat 
She will wear a coat 
Sounds right 
English has a mental state that's not based on letters written 
It's based in thought 
What is the "intended " meaning -it's a mind game